# Expression type 'NSMutableArray!' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The varible Leftover defined

```
var leftOvers : NSMutableArray!
```

i get an error when i define a for loop

```
 for leftOver: NSValue! in self.leftOvers {
}
```

The error i get is.  Expression type 'NSMutableArray!' is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know the type of the contents of `NSMutableArray` and the mutable collection types `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` cannot be implicitly bridged to Swift.

Since the contents of the array seem to be `NSValue` objects consider to declare `leftOvers` as a native Swift type. Using the `var` keyword you get mutability for free.

```
var leftOvers : [NSValue]!
```

In many cases – in particular for concrete objects like data source arrays – the array is supposed to be declared as non-optional

```
var leftOvers = [NSValue]()
```