# How to search an element in Array of Dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, search, swift3

Below mentioned is my array. I need to check if the barcode 8901058847857 or barcode xxxxxxxxxxx exists in array or not.

```
    (
        {
        barcode = 8901058847857;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Maggi Hot Heads";
        productTotal = "60.00";
        quantity = 3;
    },
        {
        barcode = 8901491101837;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Lays Classic Salted";
        productTotal = "20.00";
        quantity = 1;
    }
)
```

I tried using array.contains or array.elements but it is not working because barcode exists in an array.

Comment: you need to use NSpredicate for search .

Comment: Can you share Any example for the same?

Comment: @RajatAttri In your case it is like `if let res = yourArray.first(where: { $0["barcode"] as? String == searchingCode }) {
    print(res)
}` **Note -** Type cast `barcode` to number type if it is `Number` not `String`

Comment: @NiravD type any has no subscript members error

Comment: Nirav barcode is an Int not a String

Comment: `if array.contains(where: {$0["barcode"] as? Int ?? 0 == 8901058847857}) {`

Comment: BTW why first ? It would only check if the first element barcode is equal to that

Comment: @LeoDabus The response is from console log of Xcode so don't you think `barcode` may be String or Int.

Comment: productTotal is string barcode is Int you can tell the difference

Comment: @NiravD It is not allowing me to use Where with contains.

Comment: @RajatAttri contains is suggested by `Leo` also are you working with NSArray or swift native type array?

Comment: I am working with NSMutableArray

Comment: @RajatAttri Thats the problem

Comment: Should we use NSArray instead?

Comment: @RajatAttri What i'm saying in swift use Swift Array type `[]` instead of `NS(Mutable)Array`

Comment: @LeoDabus From the accepted answer it is look like that barcode is string not Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Try this **

```
 // Put your key in predicate that is "barcode"

var namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "barcode contains[c] %@",searchString);

let filteredArray = arrayOfDict.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };

print("names = ,\(filteredArray)")
```

Comment: Welcome @RajatAttri

Comment: Yes absolutely. It is working fine. I am getting whole dictionary calue in return.

Comment: I have an issue regarding the same. I need to check if product with this barcode exists if yes then I need to mark it selected in tableViewCell to proceed further. Can you guide me through this

I dont know how to select a cell in tableViewCell without tapping it

Comment: user will scan item and if that item is already in array then that cell will come to the top and will mark itself as selected.

Comment: are you use model class for parsing json ?

Comment: No this isn't happening in model class. I am using parsed array from other ViewController to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your array of dictionaries using contains where but you need to cast your value from `Any` to `Int` before trying to compare them:

```
if array.contains(where: {$0["barcode"] as? Int ?? 0 == 8901058847857}) { 
    print(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run for loop to check the presence of element in your Array of dictionary.

```
let DictnaryArray =     (
        {
        barcode = 8901058847857;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Maggi Hot Heads";
        productTotal = "60.00";
        quantity = 3;
    },
        {
        barcode = 8901491101837;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Lays Classic Salted";
        productTotal = "20.00";
        quantity = 1;
    }
)

for (index,element) in DictnaryArray{

let dict = DictnaryArray[index]

   if dict["barcode"] == 8901058847857 || dict["barcode"] == XXXXXXXXXXX{
     print("BarCode Exist")
     print("\(dict["barcode"])")
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it is throwing error as I am using NSMutableArray so it is saying Expression type NSMutableArray is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680790/expression-type-nsmutablearray-is-ambiguous-without-more-context